# docker-compose on ec2 instance returns Permission denied: '/etc/grub.d'

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, aws-code-deploy

I have `docker-compose --version`: `docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a` on an EC2 instance with AMI: `Amazon Linux AMI 2.0.20200319 x86_64 ECS HVM GP2`

I am able to connect through ssh, and installed `codedeploy` agent.

When running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build` it raise

`Creating network "default_default" with the default driver
Building webserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1077, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1073, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 548, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 351, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1106, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 160, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 30, in tar
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 49, in exclude_paths
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 214, in rec_walk
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 214, in rec_walk
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 184, in rec_walk
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/grub.d'
[11940] Failed to execute script docker-compose`

I search a lot in internet about it, but I am not capable to find anything related with grub.d.

Is it related to free tier AMI?

Docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-version1
    image: my_webserver
    container_name: my-container
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./library:/library
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/usr/local/airflow/logs
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    command: webserver
  scheduler:
    container_name: my-scheduler
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-version1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./library:/library
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/usr/local/airflow/logs
    ports:
      - "8793:8793"
    command: scheduler
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.1
ARG AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/"
#Allow airflow GPL dependencies
ENV SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes

#Install libraries and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip mysql-server vim

#symlink python3 to just python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python & ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

RUN set -ex \
    && buildDeps=' \
        freetds-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        git \
    '&& apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get upgrade -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        $buildDeps \
        freetds-bin \
        build-essential \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        apt-utils \
        curl \
        rsync \
        netcat \
        locales \
    && sed -i 's/^# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8$/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/g' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    #&& useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME} airflow \
    && pip install -U setuptools wheel\
    && pip install pytz \
    && pip install pyOpenSSL \
    && pip install ndg-httpsclient \
    && pip install pyasn1 \
    && pip install apache-airflow[crypto,postgres,ssh]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} \
    && pip install 'redis==3.2' \
    && if [ -n "${PYTHON_DEPS}" ]; then pip install ${PYTHON_DEPS}; fi \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -yqq $buildDeps \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf \
        /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        /tmp/* \
        /var/tmp/* \
        /usr/share/man \
        /usr/share/doc \
        /usr/share/doc-base

RUN pip install --user psycopg2-binary
RUN pip install -r requirements.pip

ADD .entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ADD .airflow.cfg ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/airflow.cfg

RUN chown -R 777 ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}
RUN chmod -R 777 /entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 8080 5432 5555 8793

WORKDIR "/"
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["webserver"]
```

Comment: A typical Docker setup won't touch GRUB settings at all (either on the host or in a container).  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidMaze done, added all dockeffile and docker-compose.yml

Comment: Are you running this from `/`? Is `Dockerfile` in `/etc/` or something like that?

Comment: @kichik yes, i run the docker-compose statement from /
Docker-compose.yml and dockerfile are in / too

Comment: Well there is your answer then. Don't do that.

Comment: @kichik they should be in a folder?

Comment: Yes. The entire folder will be sent to your docker builder. So you need to make sure all the files there are essential to the build and also that you can read them. Also look into `.dockerignore`.

Comment: @kichik that was the solution! Thank you. Post the solution and I will vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker is trying to package your entire file-system and send it to the builder. You don't have access to some of those files, like `/etc/grub.d`. Docker sends the entire context directory, minus anything specified in `.dockerignore` to the builder. You should not have that context directory be the root directory. Not only will you get these errors, but it will be slow because you package a lot of files you don't need.

Put your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files in a separate directory that's not the root directory. Ideally it should only have what you really need in the image (`.entrypoint.sh` and `.airflow.cfg`).